# Why is Sum in TOTAL in my sql doubling values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

```
SELECT dbo.tblTrackNumber.CSTPONBR, dbo.tblTrackNumber.SOPNUMBE,
    CASE WHEN dbo.tblTrackNumber.soptype = '2' THEN 'Order'
         WHEN dbo.tblTrackNumber.soptype = '3' THEN 'Invoice'
         WHEN dbo.tblTrackNumber.soptype = '4' THEN 'Return'
         WHEN tblTrackNumber.soptype = '5' THEN 'BackOrder'
    END AS SOPTYPE,
    SUM(b.subtotal) AS subtotal, b.CSTPONBR AS CUSTPO
FROM [PSOPS].ps01.dbo.SOP30200 AS b RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblTrackNumber
ON b.CSTPONBR = dbo.tblTrackNumber.CSTPONBR
WHERE (b.VOIDSTTS <> '1') AND (dbo.tblTrackNumber.SOPTYPE = '3')
GROUP BY dbo.tblTrackNumber.CSTPONBR, dbo.tblTrackNumber.SOPNUMBE,
    dbo.tblTrackNumber.SOPTYPE, b.CSTPONBR
```

Results:

Subtotal values are being doubled (79.60 should be 39.80).

```
CSTPONBR        SOPNUMBE        SOPTYPE subtotal    CUSTPO
954664-PBM      DTCI000649851   Invoice 79.60000    954664-PBM           
954673-PBM      DTCI000649852   Invoice 65.50000    954673 PBM
```

Comment: show sample data and the result you get.

Comment: explain what you are expecting and tell whats coming as result instead

Comment: Check your raw data, i.e. the query without group and sum. You will most likely notice duplicated rows. Fix this issue and you will get your expected results.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens because the `join` is generating additional rows.  The recommended solution is to aggregated the data *before* doing the `join`:

```
SELECT t.CSTPONBR, t.SOPNUMBE,
       (CASE WHEN t.soptype = '2' THEN 'Order'
             WHEN t.soptype = '3' THEN 'Invoice'
             WHEN t.soptype = '4' THEN 'Return'
             WHEN t.soptype = '5' THEN 'BackOrder'
        END) AS SOPTYPE,
    SUM(b.subtotal) AS subtotal, b.CSTPONBR AS CUSTPO
FROM dbo.tblTrackNumber t LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.cstponbr, SUM(b.substotal) as subtotal
      FROM [PSOPS].ps01.dbo.SOP30200 b
      GROUP BY b.cstponbr
    ) b
    ON b.CSTPONBR = t.CSTPONBR
WHERE (b.VOIDSTTS <> '1') AND (t.SOPTYPE = '3')
GROUP BY t.CSTPONBR, t.SOPNUMBE, t.SOPTYPE, b.CSTPONBR;
```

I also made a few other changes:

- Changed the `right join` to a `left join`.  Most people find `left join` easier to follow ("keep all rows in the first table").
- Added table aliases for the other table.

In addition, you should consider the following:

- If the `id`s are numeric, don't enclose the constants for comparison in single quotes.  This is misleading.  Strings constants for string columns.  Numeric constants for number columns.
- You probably don't need `b.CSTPONBR` in the output.  It should be the same as `t.CSTPONBR`.  You might want a flag if the records match.
- You probably do not need the `group by` any more.  Without sample data, though, it is hard to be 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I applied changes but I am getting following error:       Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'SOPNUMBE'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'VOIDSTTS'.